# Linux version of GOPupd for updating older GPUs to have GOP capability

Tags: linux, graphics-card, firmware, gop

I am trying to update the firmware of an older *ASUS NVidia GT520* graphics card (GF119) to include [GOP](https://wiki.osdev.org/GOP) capability.
There is this tool [GOPupd](https://winraid.level1techs.com/t/amd-and-nvidia-gop-update-no-requests-diy/30917) by the member "lordkag" of the WinRAID forum.

I wanted to update my graphics card according to these instructions. But the example tool is for Windows.

**Does anyone knows of a linux version to do this job (Adding a GOP_efiROM to the firmware of the graphics card)?
Or does know some other helpful information concerning this?**

This approach would apply to/improve the following AMD and NVidia GPU chipsets:

```
amd_gop_1.57.0.0.0.efirom
amd_gop.efirom
amd_gop_IDs_1.57.0.0.0.txt
amd_gop_IDs_2.4.0.0.0.txt
amd_gop_IDs.txt
amd_gop_mcu.efirom
amd_gop_mod.efirom
amd_gop_vega.efirom
nv_gop_GF10x.efirom
nv_gop_GF10x_MXM.efirom
nv_gop_GF119.efirom
nv_gop_GK1xx.efirom
nv_gop_GK1xx_multi.efirom
nv_gop_GK1xx_MXM.efirom
nv_gop_GM1xx.efirom
nv_gop_GM1xx_MXM.efirom
nv_gop_GM2xx.efirom
nv_gop_GP1xx.efirom
nv_gop_GT21x.efirom
nv_gop_GV1xx.efirom
nv_gop_TU1xx.efirom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the Windows version, I realized that it cannot be done.
The *ASUS ENGT520 SILENT/DI/1GD3(LP)* with the hardware ID **10DE:1040** and 1GB of memory has an `Atmel AT25F512` with 64kb of EEPROM space, using 61952 bytes for the default VBIOS.

So it cannot be updated with an UEFI firmware, because the firmware with GOP capability, that I created with *Windows GOPupd.exe*, has a size of 126976 bytes. Therefore it doesn't fit into the chip.

The updated VBIOS would fit into an `Atmel AT25F1024` with 128kb of space - which seems to have the same PIN layout - but I don't know enough about hardware modifications to replace the chip and then re-flash it.

The [Atmel datasheet link is here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc1440.pdf).